# chrome-extension: popup doesn't appear even with default_popup set

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've tried everything but still not showing the popup at all when I click the browser action button of my extension. Clicking the icon doesn't show the popup.html located at the directory src/cbrowser_action/popup.html, the console doesn't give me any helpful reasons why it failed. I read a lot of the other answers but it all seem to point to manifest which I can't see anything missing.

here's my manifest

```
{
  "name": "Tool",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/on.png",
    "48": "icons/on.png",
    "128": "icons/on.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "page": "src/bg/background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/on.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo",
    "default_popup" :"popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>", "management", "tabs", "webRequest","webNavigation", "webRequestBlocking", "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
  {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
       "src/lib/jquery.min.js","src/inject/content.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/content.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
asdfsup
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
console.log('loaded');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of console.log is not going to be on the page console. The console scope for the popup is the popup itself by right-clicking the browser action icon and selecting "Inspect popup".

The logging output should be visible there.